# Cancel in confirmation popup still hides div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

If user presses the "x" a dialog box comes up, if OK is pressed, div deleted, if "cancel" is pressed, then it stays put. But for some reason when I hit cancel, the div still deletes. I looked through other posts and couldn't find anything that worked. I am working in Bootstrap 3.

HTML

```
<div id="reviewInfo">

<button type="button" class="close" id="hide" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?') return true; reviewInfo(); return false">&times;</button>

<p>Hello</p>

 </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#reviewInfo").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: onclick is working properly but you are also using .click jquery that hides the div each time you click on hide button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use either onclick attribute or the jquery code at a time, right now using both of them at a time causes this issue.

try following code

```
<div id="reviewInfo">

    <button type="button" class="close" id="hide">&times;</button>

    <p>Hello</p>

    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        if (confirm("Are your sure ?")) {
            $("#reviewInfo").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It works! Xavier Doustaly above gave me the exact code as well. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you return true whatever results from confirm function.

`<button type="button" class="close" id="hide" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){ reviewInfo(); return false;}else{return true;}">&times;</button>`

Is it what you want ?

Comment: I tried that and the cancel button still hides the div.

Comment: Tried the edited version and it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: What is the function reviewInfo meant to do ?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
if(confirm('Are you sure ?')){
        $("#reviewInfo").hide();
}
    });
});`

Should do what you want if you remove the onclick attribute

Comment: It holds a few paragraphs of information that the user will have the option of deleting.